# Get mutual subscriptions between two users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follows

```
id comm_id user_id ..
```

This stores user subscriptions to communities. Now I want to query this table so that only those subscriptions are fetched which are mutual between 2 users(say user_id: 2 and 9)

Give me the sql query
tablename: db_community_subscribers
id, community_id, user_id

```
"20"      1         "2"
"28",  NULL         "2"
"31"   NULL,        "2"
"43",   4           "2"
"47     1             9
"57",   NULL,       "2"
"59",   "12",      "9"
"60     14          2
"62",  NULL         2
```

These are the subscriptions of users 2 and 9

I want to select only 1 and 12 since these are the common subscriptions

Comment: We should not give answer for such guys. they are misusing SO community.

Comment: Thanks @Somesh: We can see instant effect :)

Comment: dude. I've asked 9 questions. I answered 70 questions. I didn't know there was such a thing as accept. I thought my upvote alone decides which the accepted answer was. my bad. Since I spend most of my time here asking questions. I honestly didn't know what the tick mark does

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee does my solution works?

Comment: @johntotetwo no it didn't. I was about to comment, but the internet went off. It selects arbitrary subscriptions in addition to those mutual between them

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee, edit your question with the example and sample data, you gave me in your comment below.

Comment: I'll update with actual data. Two minutes

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee i just updated my answer.

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee: In your sample data, user 2 is not subscribed to community 12 - is there a line of data missing, or should community 12 not be returned?

Comment: yes. my mistake. I was working on the wrong dataset there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one:

I think this will work now:

```
SELECT Comm_ID
FROM tableNAme
WHERE  user_id IN (2,9)
GROUP BY Comm_ID
HAVING COUNT(Comm_ID) > 1
```

**OR**

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.Comm_ID
FROM
    (SELECT Comm_ID
    FROM tableNAme
    WHERE user_id in (1,2)) d
GROUP BY d.Comm_ID
HAVING COUNT(d.Comm_ID) > 1
```

Comment: returns only the first subscription

Comment: my bad. This works. I used wrong dataset while replacing. Sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
  SELECT group_concat(distinct comm_id)
  FROM table 
  WHERE user_id in(2, 9)
  group by user_id  having count(id) >1
```

OR:

```
  SELECT distinct comm_id
  FROM table 
  WHERE user_id in(2, 9)
  group by user_id  having count(id) >1
```

Please do required changes Let me know if anything else you want.

Comment: didn't quite work. I am updating with actual table name and structures

Comment: Done some changes check once if it's working. I have checked with sample data it's working for me

Comment: The first one returns two rows. The second one has the correct data. The first one has all the other subscriptions. So how do I only get the second one.Also you have a spelling mistake (FROM(

Comment: I think it works if you change id to community_id. That's basically, john's solution

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select comm_id, group_concat(id) as subscription_ids
from subscriptions
where user_id in (2,9)
group by comm_id
having count(distinct user_id)=2
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a simple `JOIN`?

```
SELECT t1.`community_id`
FROM `tablename` t1
LEFT JOIN tablename t2 ON (t1.`community_id` = t2.`community_id`)
WHERE t1.`user_id` = 2
    AND t2.`user_id` = 9
```

It should, for every user_id 2's community, find a matching user 9's community.

Comment: I didn't. Basically i was avoiding a join at this stage since later, I have to do 2 more joins on this query to get the community name and subcommunity id

Comment: It's probably less expensive than a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: This doesn't work. It works if you replace the first 'tablename' with t1 though. Both seem to take the same time in phpmyadmin. But I have a small dataset

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I was copying and combining names from my own setup. :)
Well, any query with `HAVING` is going to have to apply that condition *after* `GROUP`ing, without optimizations, whereas the `JOIN` can use indexes to quickly look up and match the ids.